# Realm and Runtime.getRuntime().exit(0)

Tags: android, realm

I have to restart my app in order to refresh the app state for some private reasons. To do that I am using [ProcessPheonix](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ProcessPhoenix) that is doing that well. 
The library is calling `Runtime.getRuntime().exit(0);` in order to close the process and before that it is opening some new Activities...

**The problem...**

The thing is that whenever I have a Realm instance into an Activity and call the reboot method, the app seems to be stopped and a new activity is started but it is all blank. 
I tried this with a lot of options but it seems to be doing this only when I have a realm object instantiated.

Is there something that Realm is using and should be closed or what can I do to make this work? (I tried closing the realm instance before triggering a restart and it didn't work)

**EDIT:**

[Here](https://github.com/CatalinPrata/funcodetuts/blob/master/RealmResetSample/RealmResetModule/src/main/java/com/realmreset/sample/Activity3.java) is the sample Activity. There is a superclass of Activity3 that has the realm instance.

Comment: I think You helped us find a bug. A github issue created https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1328 .  I will update here when it gets fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Realm is using native resources that need to be handled properly. That's why it requires the calling of `realm.close()`. Would you be able to properly shut down your Realm instances (all of them!) before rebooting the app?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the tip, I already tried this without any results. I also tried to delay(for about 3 seconds) the app reset after closing Realm and the same result :(. Any other ideas? Is there any other way to close or cleanup Realm? Thanks!

Comment: Not really. is there any way for you to share with us your code or to produce a sample project showing the issue?

Comment: Emanuelez, I will do that once I'll be back home as I have a demo project only for this issue. Thanks!

Comment: Emanuelez I added a link to a sample project in the question. Thanks for your time!

Comment: This has been fixed here and will be released soon :) https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/1329